# Word - Find and replace wildcard/expression

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, wildcards

Trying to figure out quickest way to set a style for specific lines of text in Word.

I've got a doc that has CHAPTER 1, CHAPTER 2, etc at the beginning of a page. The lines with CHAPTER x are all set as style "Heading 1". After the CHAPTER x line there is a return and then a line of text that is currently set as "Normal" style. I need that specific line for each chapter styled as "Heading 2" followed by 2 blank lines (the text on the next lines will stay "Normal".

To illustrate:

```
CHAPTER 15  (already set as H1)
Subhead here (which is currently Normal and needs to be H2)

Paragraphs of body text follow which are set as Normal style 
Then there is a page break and the next Chapter with another subhead to set and do the same thing to end of doc

CHAPTER 16
```

Hope that makes sense. Not sure if there is a way to find each chapter and replace to set multiple styles using wildcards or expressions?
I'm on a Mac using the latest version of Word.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to specify two different styles in Advanced Find/Replace. Probably better to use the macro recorder to record

1. an Advanced Find where you set the Find text blank and specify the
   Style as Heading 1
2. arrow down
3. apply Heading 2 style

Stop recording, then re-run that macro as many times as necessary. If you need to do this a lot it would be worth turning the recorded VBA into a loop, but up to a certain number of chapters it's probably quicker not to try to "improve" the VBA.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like it would work, but I'm not understanding the arrow down step.

Comment: Ah. Just me being stupid on the arrow down. I thought I had to define it in the find/replace. I got this working beautifully just as I wanted. Thanks again for the macro direction (first time I've used macros).